# Show Block when Listing one Content type

Tags: views, blocks

I have a silly question, i have one content type "ABC" and i have create a view page for listing all contents of that type with path "/abc". Next, i create a block which is listing all content of type "DEF", and configure the block "DEF" to show only when i'm listing the content "ABC", but not work.

Only work when i'm configure the block and put on "pages" restriction page like "/abc" path.

I'm doing something very wrong.

Any hint?

Comment: Hi there, is this question about drupal 7 or 8? please add tag.

Comment: Sorry, it's for the drupal 8. I can't edit my own post.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these instructions carefully:

1) Go to [/admin/structure/block](http:///admin/structure/block) and click on "Pleace block" button in the region you want to add your view block, for example "Content" region.

2) Now you will see at least three tabs:"Content types", "Pages", "Roles"

3) In tab "Content types" select "DEF" type content

4) Be sure on tab "Pages" is selected the radio button option "Show for the listed pages", leave empty the text area on this tab.

5) Save block.

Hope this help.

Comment: Sorry may be i didn't explain correctly or I missing something. I already do that but didn't work. First created a view for listing one type of content. And when visit the "url" /list-abc can't saw the content type of DEF. May be i'm doing something wrong.